# Strsplit colnames and rbind in R

Tags: r

I have column names in my dataframe `mydf`

```
mycols<-("cc:dd:ee","gg:dd:ee","ff:gg:dd")
```

I need to split these at ":" and rbind them to new rows in my table just below the column name itself as shown below in `result`:

mydf

```
cc:dd:ee    gg:dd:ee  ff:gg:dd
    2         4        4
    2         4        4
```

result

```
cc:dd:ee    gg:dd:ee  ff:gg:dd
    cc        gg       ff
    dd        dd       gg
    ee        ee       dd
    2         4        4
    2         4        4
```

Comment: Unless you want all your numeric data to be stored as character data, this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since data frames are really lists underneath the hood, you can achieve this by rbind-ing the results of a `strsplit` of the column names:

```
df <- data.frame(c("2", "2"), c("4", "4"), c("4","4"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(df) <- c("cc:dd:ee","gg:dd:ee","ff:gg:dd")
df <- rbind(strsplit(colnames(df), ":"), df)
```

Comment: Why do I get this error: > df <- rbind(strsplit(colnames(df), ":"), df)
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c("cc", "dd", "ee")) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c("gg", "dd", "ee")) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c("ff", "gg", "dd")) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @user277653 - the data.frame columns in Scott's example are `factor`s, which only accept a limited range of values when replacing. Try it with `df <- data.frame(c("2", "2"), c("4", "4"), c("4","4"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`